# Save data to Cassandra from Kafka using Spring Batch with high throughput

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-batch, spring-kafka, batch-processing

I need to consume data from Kafka and store it in Cassandra DB using Spring Batch. Let's say that the data is an object with a String id Primary key and int status code. The volume of messages is in millions of messages per minute. How do I efficiently and rapidly store the data into Cassandra DB?

Currently I am using Kafka Listener to consume data place it in a queue and poll data from ItemReader.

```
ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DeviceStatusTracker> dataFromKafka = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

Kafka Deserializer

```
@Component
public class MessageDeserializer implements Deserializer<Message> {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperFactory.getObjectMapper();

    public DeviceStatusTrackerDeserializer() {
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(java.util.Map<java.lang.String,?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        // No additional configuration required
    }

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(java.lang.String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            if (data == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return objectMapper.readValue(data, Message.class);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException("Error serializing Message", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have noticed that increasing the concurrency increases the time to complete the step. The topic has 5 partitions with 2 replicas.

```java
@KafkaListener(
        id = "topic-kafka-listener",
        groupId = "topic-batch",
        containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory",
        concurrency = "1",
        topics = "topic"
)
public void receive(@NotNull @Payload List<Message> messages) {
    dataFromKafka.addAll(messages);
}
```

```
@StepScope
public ItemReader<Message> itemReader() {
    return () -> dataFromKafka.poll();
}

@StepScope
public ItemWriter<Message> itemWriter() {
    return (chunk) -> messageRepository.saveAll(chunk.getItems());
}
```

```
public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(8);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(16);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(100);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.setPrestartAllCoreThreads(true);
    threadPoolTaskExecutor.initialize();
    return threadPoolTaskExecutor;
}

@Bean
public Job job(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new JobBuilder("job", jobRepository)
         .start(step1(jobRepository, transactionManager))
         .build();
}


public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<Message, Message>chunk(10000, transactionManager)
            .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor())
            .reader(itemReader())
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

I am using this to run the Job Periodically and to find out the resources used.

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Runnable runnable = () -> {
    try {
        JobParameters jobParameter = new JobParametersBuilder()
                    .addLocalTime("time", LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalTime())
                    .toJobParameters();

        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameter);

        double cpuUsage = osBean.getProcessCpuLoad() * 100;
        double usedMemory = memoryMXBean.getHeapMemoryUsage().getUsed() / 1048576.0;

        logger.info("CPU Usage: " + cpuUsage + " %");
        logger.info("Used Memory: " + usedMemory + " MB");
   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
};

executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I have also tried to pause the Kafka listener, split data into batches and place them into the queue and resume Kafka listener. The item reader then polls for a list of messages instead of polling one by one. But this resulted in dropped messages.

Hardware info:

- Ryzen 7 4800 H Octa Core
- 16GB RAM
- SSD

Currently this code takes 2 minutes to store 1 million messages into cassandra.
I suspect the choke point is the queue. What is the best way to split the data and give it to the threads instead of polling one by one?
What other methods should I try to make it faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`I have noticed that increasing the concurrency increases the time to complete the step` Ah yeah, your hardware probably isn't powerful enough to handle the current set up you have...

There are lots of moving parts here, so I will just throw a couple of thoughts at you to see if anything might help!

---

Your chunk size is 10000, have you experimented with higher or lower values to see what kind of affect his has?

---

You may be able to leverage https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

And use this for your item writing code. Something like:

```html
public Step step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) {
    return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
            .<Message, Message>chunk(10000, transactionManager)
            .taskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor())
            .reader(itemReader())
            .writer((chunk) -> itemWriter(chunk))
            .build();
}
```

```html
public CompletableFuture<Void> itemWriter(List<Message> chunk) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> messageRepository.saveAll(chunk.getItems()));
}
```

---

Similar to the above, maybe leverage streams if the version of Java you are using supports it: https://www.baeldung.com/java-when-to-use-parallel-stream

---

Hoping these ideas spur something that'll help!

Comment: I have tried changing the chunk size to higher and lower. The time difference was not very noticeable. Unless the chunk size was close to the number of messages it needed to parse making it slower, I will try your suggestions and get back. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I was not able to calculate the exact time due since the step ends before the writing is done but it reduced the time by approx 4 to 5 times. 1 million data written in around 30 seconds and 5 million in 2mins 30 seconds.

Had to change some of it.
`(chunk) -> itemWriter(chunk.getItems())`

`public CompletableFuture<Void> itemWriter(List<? extends Message> chunk)`

Comment: Oh wow, great results! So glad this helped :)

Comment: I just noticed an issue. I inserted 5 million messages but when I checked the number in the database there is only around 2 million. I tried again and it was around 1.4 million. There are a lot of messages being dropped.

Comment: When i inserted 500,000 there was no drop in messages. I tried with 750,000 around 15,200 were missing in the database.

Comment: I inserted 1 million data multiple times. sometimes all of them are inserted or sometimes some are dropped.

Comment: I am guessing that the message drops are due to my RAM getting full. When I limit the number of messages processed at a time to a certain extent it works great.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of moving components, it is not easy to diagnose (Kafka, Cassandra, batch, the resources on your machines).

1. 1M/Min = 16k msg/s For Cassandra it is not a problem at all but your cluster needs to have enough nodes, the rule of thumbs is 3k/s per core and per node.
2. Add an `application.conf` file in your project to start tuning Cassandra drivers (consistency level, thread pool, ...) => [Documentation HERE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.16/manual/core/configuration/#quick-overview)
3. I am not very confident with this high abstraction from Spring Data Cassandra...`messageRepository.saveAll(chunk.getItems())`. If you have a lot of items it can take a while and not distributing the writes.

I am afraid CompletableFuture.runAsync() will not help... you need to send unitary writes as async except if all chunks are part of the same partition in CASSANDRA ...with a BATCH STATEMENT preferably.

I would try something like:

```java
chunk.getItems().stream().parallel().forEach(messageRepository::saveAsync);
```

I do not know if there is a reactive component to Spring Batch but that would also help on [Cassandra's side](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-cassandra-reactive), as the reactive drivers have some back pressure mechanisms.

Comment: I tried the command but it gave an error saying `Cannot resolve method 'saveAsync'`
In the code completion there is only save and saveall